# RDS Security groups - default only working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-security-group

I'm new to AWS and RDS. I've combed through help files and other stackflow questions, but can't seem to find out if i'm doing something wrong. 
When I go to my RDS Instance, I see
**Security Groups:default( active )**
I click default, and it takes me to the SG page, where I create new groups.
However, any rules I put in those new groups don't work, only the rules I put in the default group works.  In some of the documentation, I see the screenshots and the beside the Security Groups on the instance page, it doesn't list default, but a user created group.

So is there some way to make all the new groups active or a way to change which group has precedence on that Instance page? Or am I going to have to put all my rules in the default group?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Update:**

You can now change a RDS security group, see user115813's answer a few pixels under my original answer.

Please feel free to validate his answer instead of mine.

Comment: Thanks. It would be helpful if that was documented somewhere or at least where I could find it cause it wasn't in the security groups docs. But maybe people with RDS already have and EC2 set up, whereas I creates an RDS to work with EMR.  thanks!!! I hate when things seem mysterious

Comment: Do you mean something like that? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html

Comment: Hi thibaultd, I read through that documentation, but since I wasn't using any EC2, i didn't really see how it applied to those only using RDS and EMR, I never spun up EC2. But with your answer and looking over the document it makes sense now. I'm just getting started. Thanks again!

Comment: What?? Both statements in this answer seem to be false - My RDS instance *can* have multiple security groups, and I *can* change these groups after launching.

Comment: My answer may be out of date, as things change. I'll have to check.

Comment: Edited my answer to link to the right answer. I can't change the fact that it's validated, so if you want to notify the ask-er then comment the question instead of my answer.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem trying to modify security group right from the top-level view of instances. [The Postgres RDS setup has it backwards, having me create the instance and *then* telling me I have to do the security group thing, saying only "see startup guide" and providing a broken link to that. :)]

Anyway, I finally figured out I had to select the running instance and then under instance actions select "Modify" and then there is a nice friendly widget for changing the security group.

Comment: THANK YOU this is not obvious at all, was causing a lot of headache